# Android studio Grid Layout refresh

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a problem that I can't figure out. I think it's really simple, but just don't know how to do it.

I have a `GridLayout` with 24 rows and 5 columns, and all cells contain a `CardView`. For example, this is my `layout.xml` (in small version):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="RefreshWarehouse">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="24"
        android:onClick="RefreshWarehouse">

        //Accessories

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1CView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1Image"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/money"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="AccessoriesBoxLVL - 1"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1Image"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Open"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1Button"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1TView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="openAccessoriesBoxLVL1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1TView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Count: "
                    android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL1Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2CView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2Image"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/money"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="AccessoriesBoxLVL - 2"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2Image"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Open"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2Button"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2TView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:onClick="openAccessoriesBoxLVL2"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2TView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Count: "
                    android:textColor="#8b8b8b"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AccessoriesBoxLVL2Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And I have made all `visibility="gone"` and I have a refresh method that sets `visibility="visible"`:

```
if(Box.Accessories[0] > 0){
    ((CardView) findViewById(R.id.AccessoriesBoxLVL1CView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if(Box.Accessories[4] > 0){
    ((CardView) findViewById(R.id.AccessoriesBoxLVL2CView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if(Box.Accessories[8] > 0){
    ((CardView) findViewById(R.id.AccessoriesBoxLVL3CView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if(Box.Accessories[12] > 0){
    ((CardView) findViewById(R.id.AccessoriesBoxLVL4CView)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But problem is that I can't figure out how to make each `CardView` show in line(horziontaly), not in their positions like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I advise you to do, is to use a GridLayout with an Adapter and dynamically add the CardViews into the adapter, which will result in showing them the way you want. This means the cards will **not** be in the GridLayout, until you decide you want them there.

Please refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) and look for "Building Layout with an Adapter" for understanding how this design pattern work and implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, will check out :)

Comment: No problem, this will be very useful for you as the usage of adapters is very fundamental in Android